# Getting 403 Forbidden error message when trying to access a cusotm route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 to develop my project and in this project, I have added this route:

```
Route::namespace('StaticPages')->prefix('tavana')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'TavanaStaticController@index')->name('tavanaMainFrontend');
    ...
});
```

So when I goto the url `sitename.com/tavana/`, it should be retrieving data from `TavanaStaticController` Controller.

But now the problem I'm facing is that, it shows **403 Forbidden**:

> **Forbidden** You don't have permission to access this resource.

This is strange, because it used to work fine!

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: please share TavanaStaticController code

Comment: First use auth and/or login route, cache the token, then pass token (in any other route request).

Comment: Please share your Controller codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was basically because of these codes written at `.htaccess` file in `public` directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

So when I go to a url like `/example` on my website,  it searches in `public` directory and if not any folder name exists with the same name, then it will calls the Controller and its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command and see if a middleware is specified for this path or not

```
php artisan route:list
```

In the middleware column you will see the items that cause you to make a 403 error.
Check out that middleware